# How to get the distinct count of a column using C

Tags: c, string, count, distinct

I would like to get the distinct count of the column of a large data file using C.How can I do it.Please kindly advise me.Thanks.My sample data file is as below.

For 2nd attribute the distinct count is 6.

```
399547,v4149,p3178,1990,2065,fraud
399940,v5852,p3194,8278,2180,fraud
399983,v3476,p3199,766,1125,fraud
400206,v3467,p3216,494,311000,fraud
400345,v4497,p3219,1211,432100,fraud
400471,v3473,p3225,41392,3710,fraud
400498,v3476,p3225,102,23820,fraud
401325,v4497,p3297,1322,1110,fraud
```

Comment: What did you try?  What are you thinking of trying — and why didn't you try it?

Answer (score 2):

Make a search tree for every column. Let's say you have 10 rows in a file with 2 distinct values for the `nth` column viz. `3456` and `3457`. Your search tree for `nth` column will look like:
[image: Search tree for nth column]

You'll end up with 6 Search trees. Once you have read the entire file, traverse all possible paths in each search tree and that will give you the number of distinct values.

Comment: +1 for a really fancy solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Read and split every line.
- Put the second attributes into an array.
- [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) the array

You have now an array with equal strings adjacent to each other. You can loop over the array and count different entries.

If your entries are all 5 characters long, otherwise you must `malloc()` memory for each attribute.

```
char (*array)[6];
int i;
int n; /* number of lines read */
int distinct = 1;
/* read the data file and put it into array */
/* qsort() array */
for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(array[i], array[i - 1]) != 0)
        ++distinct;
}

printf("There are %d distinct rows\n", distinct);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::map<std::string,int>` - it will hold key-value pairs, where key is vNNNN, and value is number of repetitions.

First loop will scan input file and populate this map, then number of keys in map will be distinct count.

**EDIT:** If you cannot use C++ and do require C, you will have to find some hashmap library for C, like [sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/).

If amount of data is really, really big, it is possible that it will not fit in memory. In this case, I would recommend to use SQLite temporary database to parse, store and index your data and then use standard `SELECT DISTINCT` on it.

Comment: This works in C++, but not in C :(